# AutoIt like GUI automation tool for Java

Tags: java, swing, automation

I need to automate UI testing of a software that my module is plugged in. I do not have an access to code of the host so I need something like AutoIt. Since AutoIt does not work with Swing,  is there any **AutoIt like** GUI automation tool for JAVA based applications?

Answer (score 4):

You can take a look at [Marathon](http://www.marathontesting.com/), it is for Java.

Answer (score 3):

Java Swing applications can be automated using [Jubula](http://www.eclipse.org/jubula/) Functional Testing Tool.

Answer (score 1):

I like very much [Fest](http://code.google.com/p/fest/) but I don't know Autoit :(

Comment: I do not own the larger portion of the code so I need a automation tool that records and replays or enables scripting rather than an API or a Framework.

Answer (score 1):

TestComplete supports Java, and does not require you to add code to the program you are testing.

Answer (score 1):

Auto can probably do it ? Try the AutoIT JAVA UDF that a friend of mine wrote, it is quite old and may not work anymore..my apols

This UDF currently automates standalone applications and browser-based applets, developed in either **Swing** or the Abstract Window Toolkit (AWT).

[JAVA UDF](http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/87956-java-udf/)

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try out [JWinAuto](http://jwinauto.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 0):

I've heard of [sikuli](http://www.sikuli.org/) being used for automating java apps